# Button is not 'Material' inside dialog

Tags: angular, angular-material

Everything is working but for some reason the button has not 'material' design to it.
the dialog is a separate component

app.compnent.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getAnalytics } from "firebase/analytics";
import { faCoffee } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';
import { faLinkedinIn, faLinkedin, faGithub} from '@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons';
import { MaterialExampleModule } from '../material.module';
import {DialogOverviewExample, DialogOverviewExampleDialog} from 'src/tutorial/tutorial.component'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {

  constructor(public tut: DialogOverviewExample){}

  title = 'file';
  faLinked = faLinkedin;
  faGithub = faGithub;

  showDialog(){
    this.tut.openDialog();
  }
```

app.module.ts

```
import { ApplicationInitStatus, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { MaterialExampleModule } from '../material.module';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import {FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
import {MatNativeDateModule} from '@angular/material/core';
import {HttpClientModule} from '@angular/common/http';
import { FontAwesomeModule } from '@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome';
import { DialogOverviewExample } from '../tutorial/tutorial.component';
import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material/button'


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    MatNativeDateModule,
    MaterialExampleModule,
    FontAwesomeModule,
    MatButtonModule,
  ],
  exports:[
    MatButtonModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { 
  
}
```

tutorial.component.ts

```
import {Component, Inject, Injectable, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {MatDialog, MatDialogRef, MAT_DIALOG_DATA} from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { MaterialExampleModule } from '../material.module';
import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material/button'


export interface DialogData {
  animal: string;
  name: string;
}

@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root"
})

@Component({
  selector: 'app-tutorial',
  templateUrl: './tutorial.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./tutorial.component.css']
})
export class DialogOverviewExample {
  animal: string | undefined;
  name: string | undefined;

  constructor(public dialog: MatDialog) {}

  openDialog(): void {
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DialogOverviewExampleDialog, {
      width: 'auto',
      height: 'auto',
      data: {name: this.name, animal: this.animal},
    });

    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
      console.log('The dialog was closed');
      this.animal = result;
    });
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'tutorial.component',
  templateUrl: 'tutorial.component.html',
})
export class DialogOverviewExampleDialog {
  constructor(
    public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<DialogOverviewExampleDialog>,
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: DialogData,public dialog: MatDialog
  ) {}

  onNoClick(): void {
    this.dialogRef.close();
  }
}
```

tutorial.component.html

```
<button mat-button mat-dialog-close>Close</button>
<a mat-raised-button routerLink=".">test</a>
```

I could not post my question because of "It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details." I do not have anything else to add...

Comment: You probably need to import MatButtonModule to whatever module declares your modal component.

Comment: MatButtonModule is imported in 'tutorial.component.ts' and 'app.module.ts' , it needs to be imported also somewhere else?

Comment: Try importing also in whatever module owns tutorial component.

Comment: I agree, probably an 'import' is missing somewhere. I created tutorial component with 'ng generate component...' command so it created three files - html, css, typescript. no module file.

Comment: There should be some module that lists the tutorial component in its declarations array.